# Firebase doesn't log ITEM_ID

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-analytics

I am using Firebase for my android app.

I want to track, I have a `BaseDrawerActivity` class which is the father of all other activity classes.

I log all the activities seen on the screen using this in `BaseDrawerActivity`

```
protected void onResume() {
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    Log.i("logging..",getClass().toString());
    bundle.putString(FirebaseAnalytics.Param.ITEM_ID, getClass().toString());
    bundle.putString(FirebaseAnalytics.Param.ITEM_NAME, "Activity");
    bundle.putString(FirebaseAnalytics.Param.CONTENT_TYPE, "text");
    mFirebaseAnalytics.logEvent(FirebaseAnalytics.Event.SELECT_CONTENT, bundle);
    super.onResume();
    barcodeView.resume();
}
```

But in the Firebase panel, it only shows the `item_id` for one of the activities. I can see the `logging` Log in my android monitor.

[image]

I have no idea how to debug/fix this.

Comment: Don't you know that Firebase already logs automatically the Activities seen by users and how long they are shown?

Comment: It's `not set`. Just like the event.

Comment: Please add a screenshot of your Firebase events dashboard.

Comment: @dalla92 added the screenshot.

Comment: What you want to track? I can see your class.

Comment: This is just one of the activity classes. The others are just `not set`

Answer (score 0):

It looks like in the ITEM_ID parameter you are tracking the screen name. Since you have not set any name for you screens they are tracked as (not set) in the ITEM_ID parameter.

Try setting the screens using the *[setCurrentScreen](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/analytics/FirebaseAnalytics.html#setCurrentScreen(android.app.Activity,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String))* method. This would help SDK to set the name of the screen instead of tracking them under (not set).

Read more under [Track Screens](https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics/screenviews) doc.